# Java String get a paticular value

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java. I  have a `String` and want to take a particular value

Eg:

```
String date = "20150531"; //Format yyyyddmm
```

I want to get the value 05(month) alone from the above string.

Comment: Ever heard of substring?

Comment: @cvesters perhaps it would sound more friendly if you would suggest user3492471 to look at the String.class -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ... If the user knew the answer the user wouldn't ask

Comment: My apologies, I don't mean to be rude but I'm not always very subtle, something I should work on ;)

Comment: By the way the format in the comment is not what you told. It must be `yyyymmdd`

Answer (score 2):

You could change the Date Format.

If you don't want to do so. Use the `substring()` method.

```
String date = "20150531";
String month = date.substring(4,6);
```

How does a substring method work?

Here it took 2 integers, 4 and 6.

```
Date = 2 0 1 5 0 5 3 1
index= 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
               ^ ^
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's not what we need. When we could just get the value using `substring` repalace takes much overhead which we don't want here.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format then you try as below also:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddmm");
String dateStr="20150531";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( sf.parse(dateStr) );
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```